# Why can't I require a constructor and immediately use it with browserify?

Tags: javascript, commonjs, browserify

The two following lines of code should do exactly the same thing. The first one is a bit more verbose, but this should be the only difference. Still, the 2nd example results in an error. Why?

The following works:

```
var Model = require('./Model');
new Model();
```

However, the following results in `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './Model'`

```
new require('./Model')();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with the operator precedence. If you do this, it will work:

```
new (require("./Model"))();
```

What was happening is:

```
(new require("./Model"))()
```

Comment: Yep, I found also the following github issue that explained it in more detail: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/563